# prove that $(f_n(x))$ converges uniformly in $[a,b]$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here's the question:

Let $f(x)$ be continuously differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$, and let $f_n=n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))$.

Find $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$, and prove that $(f_n(x))$ converges uniformly in $[a,b]$ for every $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$.

The first part was relatively simple, i found that:

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}n(f(x+1/n)-f(x))=\displaystyle\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = f'(x)$.

For the second part i was considering using Dini's theorem, but im not sure if its even possible to prove that $(f_n)$ is monotonic... any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the MVT helps:
$$
f_n(x) = n \left( f'(\xi(x,n)) \frac{1}{n} \right)
$$
for some
$$
x < \xi(x,n) < x+ \frac{1}{n}.
$$
Now use the fact that $\xi(x,n) \to x$ as $n \to +\infty$ and that $f'$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]$.